# Windows DHCP issue BAD_ADDRESS

Tags: windows, dhcp, microsoft-surface

This is interesting. we have several MS Surface's with MS docks and we are connecting then via Ethernet.

We are noticing that these Surface's when connecting through dock are causing BAD_ADDRESS in the DHCP and thus making all available IPs unusable. So we have to manually clear them. This does not happen with WiFi or any other computers.

I have updated the firmware of the MS docks to the latest and still having this issue.

The DHCP Log states:

```
2,01/29/19,08:19:22,DNS Update Successful,10.10.0.231,Surface3-001.XYZ.com,,,0,6,,,,,,,,,0
30,01/29/19,08:21:14,DNS Update Request,10.10.0.231,Surface3-001.XYZ.com,,,0,6,,,,,,,,,0
11,01/29/19,08:21:14,Renew,10.10.0.231,Surface3-001.XYZ.com,B831B52E457F,,2769639364,0,,,,0x4D53465420352E30,MSFT 5.0,,,,0
```

This is repeated for all BAD_ADDRESS.

We have assigned static IP (10.10.0.231) to this particular Surface but it is still doing this.

DHCP and DNS is on primary DC on MS 2012-R2 server.
2nd DNS is on backup DC.

Any ideas?
Edit:

To be more specific under Scope > Address Leases. So basically it is leasing out the IP but no one is getting those thus making it a BAD_ADDRESS. In the DHCP logs I see the entries mentioned above related to all the BAD_ADDRESSES.
We do not have any other DHCP server running besides the Sonicwall which only provides IPs to wireless devices and VPN clients.

Comment: For other Surfaces we have put them on wifi to avoid this. but would like to use the Ethernet on the dock as wifi signals in the building are too many and cause interference.

Comment: So where exactly are you seeing the `BAD_ADDRESS` error? Please [edit] the question to clarify this.

Comment: Hi DavidPostil, Thanks for replying, I did mention it is in the DHCP server. To be more specific under Scope >  Address Leases.  So basically it is leasing out the IP but no one is getting those thus making it a BAD_ADDRESS. We do not have any other DHCP server running besides the Sonicwall which only provides IPs to wireless devices and VPN clients.